# Yarn container lauch failed exception and mapred-site.xml configuration

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have 7 nodes in my Hadoop cluster [8GB RAM and 4VCPUs to each nodes], 1 Namenode + 6 datanodes.

**EDIT-1@ARNON:** I followed the link, mad calculation according to the hardware configruation on my nodes and have added the update mapred-site and yarn-site.xml files in my question. Still my application is crashing with the same exection

My mapreduce application has 34 input splits with a block size of 128MB.

**mapred-site.xml** has the  following properties:

```
mapreduce.framework.name  = yarn
mapred.child.java.opts    = -Xmx2048m
mapreduce.map.memory.mb   = 4096
mapreduce.map.java.opts   = -Xmx2048m
```

**yarn-site.xml** has the  following properties:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.hostname        = hadoop-master
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services        = mapreduce_shuffle
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb  = 6144
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 2048
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 6144
```

**EDIT-2@ARNON:**   Setting yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb to 4096 puts all the map task in suspended state and assigning it as 3072 crashes with the follwoing

```
Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=134: /bin/bash: line 1:  3876 Aborted  (core dumped) /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx8192m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-ubuntu/nm-local-dir/usercache/ubuntu/appcache/application_1424264025191_0002/container_1424264025191_0002_01_000011/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/home/ubuntu/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1424264025191_0002/container_1424264025191_0002_01_000011
-Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 192.168.0.12 50842 attempt_1424264025191_0002_m_000005_0 11 > 
/home/ubuntu/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1424264025191_0002/container_1424264025191_0002_01_000011/stdout 2> 
/home/ubuntu/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1424264025191_0002/container_1424264025191_0002_01_000011/stderr
```

How can avoid this?any help is appreciated

Is there an option to restrict number of containers on hadoop ndoes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are allocating too much memory your tasks (even without looking at all the configurations) 8GB RAM and 8GB per map task and all of which is heap
Try to use lower allocations 2Gb with 1GB heap or something like that

Comment: Thanks.Updated the parameters as follows: .....
mapred.child.java.opts    = -Xmx2048m
mapreduce.map.memory.mb   = 4096
mapreduce.map.java.opts   = -Xmx2048m, MapReduce crashing at 0%..................Exception from container-launch: ExitCodeException exitCode=134: /bin/bash: line 1: 10390 Aborted                 (core dumped) /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx2048m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-ubuntu/nm-local-

Comment: Thanks.

Updated the parameters as follows: .....

mapred.child.java.opts = -Xmx2048m

mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 4096

mapreduce.map.java.opts = -Xmx2048m

Comment: There ar more parameters to set when you're using YARN - see this for example http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html

Comment: Edited my question above, Still have ing problems, Please see EDIT-1 & EDIT-2